# Modify vector so it can be invoked with two arguments

Tags: clojure

I'm playing with a matrix implementation in Clojure which I'm doing for the fun of doing it and learning more about Clojure, rather than because I want to create the bestest fastest most coolest matrix implementation in the world.

One of the primary operations needed in code like this is the ability to return the value at a given row and column in a matrix, which of course I've written as a function

```
(mat-getrc m 2 3)
```

says "Give me the value at row 2, column 3 in matrix m". Perfectly good Clojure, but verbose and **ugly**. I'd *rather* write

```
(m 2 3)
```

but of course A) vectors (in my package matrices are just vectors) only respond to a single argument, and B) vectors don't know how to use the row and column number to figure out where the correct value is stored.

From looking at [the docs for `IFn`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/javadoc/clojure/lang/IFn.html) (which vectors are supposed to implement) it appears that a two-argument version of `invoke` exists - but how do I get my "matrix" vectors to implement and respond to it?

Any suggestions and pointing-in-the-right-direction appreciated.

Comment: How important is the "a matrix is just a regular vector" property to you? That is to say -- is it *really* important to you that you modify the way *all* vectors work, as opposed to having only a specific kind of object that is considered a matrix (and, since you want it to be vector-y, implements the interface [`clojure.lang.IPersistentVector`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IPersistentVector.java))?

Comment: It wouldn't bother me if all vectors suddenly started being invoke-able with two arguments. As I've got them implemented a matrix looks like `[[3 2] 1 2 3 4 5 6]`, where the element at index zero is itself a two-element vector representing the number of rows and columns in the matrix, and the following elements are the values of the matrix in row-major order. Earlier this evening I was thinking about the alternative implementation suggested by @ChrisMurphy (e.g. `[[1 2 3][4 5 6]`) but given that my current implementation presents some interesting challenges I think I'll stick with it. :-)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: but, following up further on your comment, I also wouldn't mind implementing a specific kind of object as a matrix. The attraction of the current implementation is sticking with "standard" Clojure types, with the idea that "It's better to have a few types and a lot of functions which operate on them, than a lot of different types with a few functions operating on each". But as this is a play-time project for me I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: @BobJarvis *You* might be happy if all vectors started acting this way, but what if another loaded library wanted all vectors to start treating a two-argument IFn call as if it were `assoc`? eg, `('[x y z] 1 'a)` returning `'[x a z]`. Both seem reasonable enough at first glance, but cannot coexist, which is evidence that neither is a reasonable thing for a library author to be able to do. Instead, do as Charles Duffy suggests, and define a separate type for matrices, which can behave exactly as you want; leave plain vectors alone.

Comment: In case you haven't seen it, [`core.matrix`](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix) does what you want.

Comment: @Thumbnail: many thanks for pointing this out. Although `core.matrix` is probably a much better matrix package than anything I'll implement it doesn't teach me *how* to implement such a package in Clojure. Implementing linear algebra is something I use as a learning exercise in many languages I set out to learn, so my purpose here is to go through the process of writing the routines, rather than using them. If I want high performance and reliability I'll (probably :-) use `core.matrix`, but for purposes of learning I'll go through the exercise of doing it myself.

Comment: Yes. It was the interface/API I thought you might find helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify how vectors are invoked as that's built into the implementation of vector, but you can define your own type that wraps a vector, acts as a vector, and is invokable however you like with `deftype`. You would need to extend many of the same interfaces that vectors implement (this is however a large list):

```
user=> (ancestors clojure.lang.PersistentVector)
#{clojure.lang.IEditableCollection clojure.lang.ILookup 
  java.util.concurrent.Callable java.lang.Runnable clojure.lang.IMeta 
  java.lang.Comparable clojure.lang.IReduceInit
  clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection clojure.lang.IHashEq java.lang.Iterable 
  clojure.lang.IReduce java.util.List clojure.lang.AFn clojure.lang.Indexed 
  clojure.lang.Sequential clojure.lang.IPersistentStack java.io.Serializable 
  clojure.lang.Reversible clojure.lang.Counted java.util.Collection 
  java.util.RandomAccess java.lang.Object clojure.lang.Seqable 
  clojure.lang.Associative clojure.lang.APersistentVector 
  clojure.lang.IKVReduce clojure.lang.IPersistentVector clojure.lang.IObj 
  clojure.lang.IFn}
```

Comment: Hurray! Another windmill! Sancho - bring forth my lance! :-) I haven't investigated `deftype` before - I'll look into this. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
(def matrix [[1 2 3 4][5 6 7 8][9 10 11 12]])
```

As you say in your question this is possible:

```
(matrix 2)
```

But this is not:

```
(matrix 2 3)
```

This would be a standard way to get the index of an index:

```
(get-in matrix [2 3])
```

You can already nearly get what you want, just with a few more parens:

```
((matrix 2) 3)
```

You could define a higher order function:

```
(defn matrix-hof [matrix]
  (fn [x y]
    (get-in matrix [x y])))
```

Then put the function rather than the matrix in function position:

```
(let [m (matrix-hof matrix)]
    (m 2 3))
```

I don't believe that exactly what you are asking is possible using either a function or a macro.